# 550 SPF Error: SPF Permanent Error: Two or more type TXT spf records found

Tags: email, dns, smtp, spf

some customers (not all ones) have problems when they try to send us emails.

Their mail server respond with the following error:

> 550 SPF Error: SPF Permanent Error: Two or more type TXT spf records found.

but we have double checked the DNS and there is only one record TXT containing spf info, this one:

> ourdomain.com         300     IN      TXT     "v=spf1 include:spf.helprace.com include:amazonses.com ~all"

Even digging with `dig ourdomain.com TXT | grep spf` give us exactly the same response as the record configured in our DNS NS:

> ourdomain.com.         300     IN      TXT     "v=spf1 include:spf.helprace.com include:amazonses.com ~all"

So where does this error come from?

I've also tried to check on https://mxtoolbox.com for ourdomain.com, but no particular issue seems detected:
[image]

... so where can be the issue? (and how can we solve it?)

Thank you all,

Comment: Is `ourdomain.com` your real domain? I Don't see any of the same results as you posted in your screen-shot

Comment: No it is not, I've just replaced the real domain name, but the test results are from the real one.

Answer (score 0):

The Sender Policy Framework relates to verification of the sender's IP addresses, not the receiving host.

This has nothing to do with your own SPF record.

If your customers cannot send to you, then it very well may be that your receiving server is rejecting their SPF records.